# Incorrect XML deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following class:

```
public class FtpDefinition
{
    public FtpDefinition()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        FtpServerAddress = string.Empty;
        FtpPortSpecified = false;
        FtpPort = "21";
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Id")]
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("FtpServerAddress")]
    public string FtpServerAddress { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("FtpPortSpecified")]
    public bool FtpPortSpecified  { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("FtpPort")]
    public string FtpPort { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that gets the following XML string, and using the .net XML deserialization capability
deserializes it into an object of type FtpDefinition.

```
<FTPDefinition>
  <Id>a0a940a7-6785-41be-ac3a-75ba5d4c13ee</Id>
  <FtpServerAddress>ftp.noname.com</FtpServerAddress>
  <FtpPortSpecified>false</FtpPortSpecified>
  <FtpPort>21</FtpPort>
</FTPDefinition>
```

The problem is, that although the Id and FtpServerAddress fields get populated properly, FtpPort gets
populated with an empty string, and what's more weird is that FtpPortSpecified gets populated with the bool value TRUE instead of FALSE.

I replaced the automatic properties in the above code with actual return\... = value old style getter\setter, so that I can catch the setter getting hit. I was suspecting there's some user code setting the value, but this is not the case. In the call stack it clearly shows that the .net deserialization code is calling the setter with the value TRUE, but one can also see that the XML string provided as parameter to the deserializing method has the correct value (FALSE).

The deserialization code is simple:

```
XmlSerializer xs =  ...(objectType);

using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    return xs.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Please help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In the ctor you use the property PortSpecified where is the def of it ? I only see FtpPortSpecified

Comment: Fixed it. Copy-paste error when I created the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `Specified` suffix has some special behavior in XML Serialization. Simply change `FtpPortSpecified` to something else.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb402199(v=exchg.140).aspx